# Debugging Help: Wrapped c++ DLL running fine in one application, crashing another

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, dll, unmanaged

I'm migrating some C# Demo Code from a Command Window Application to an WPF Application. The Demo Code is accessing a wrapped unmanaged C++ Library. The library is provided by a third party, so I don't have access to the code.

While the Demo Code is running fine, the exact same code crashes in my WPF application after a while. The library is accessed, some configuration files are loaded but when I'm calling a certain method my application is throwing an error (I had to enable "Unmanaged Code Debuggin" to see it):

```
First-chance exception at 0x7726c41f in Application.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x279ce1b4..
SCAPE exception caught: bad allocation
```

This is the part where the error is thrown:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (S_DATA* pim = &_im)
    {
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
             success = RunAnalytics(_im); // <--- returns false, error message in debugger
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ScrException("ERROR: Unmanaged exception", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Both applications are running on  ".NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile".

Any hints how to proceed from here on? I'm out of ideas...

**Edit:**
I spent the last days setting up different scenarios trying to figure out, what's the source for the issue.

- Original WPF in Original Solution > fails
- Original WPF in Dummy Solution > works
- Dummy CMD in Original Solution > works
- Dummy CMD in Dummy Solution > works
- Minimal WPF in Dummy Solution > works
- Minimal WPF in Original Solution > works

I'm not really any wiser...

**Edit 2:** After a long, long time I figured it out - a post-build script interfered with some local resources that were copied on top of one another, so I was using an outdated configuration file with some new settings... not a very satisfying solution.

Comment: You will also need to enable native debugging.  That will allow you to step into the C++ code.  Alternatively, pop up a MsgBox on entry into the C++ code.  If the single stepping works, it should break on the first statement after the msgbox.  Make sure the .pdb for the C++ dll is in the same directory.

Comment: You are trying to allocate more memory than you have available. Possibly because of some error where some "how much to allocate" turns into a negative number. So, without seeing what is going on inside `RunAnalytics`, it's impossible to say what is wrong with that code.

Comment: @cup: I don't have the according .pdb file nor the code for the dll. I do have an .exp and .lib file.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Thanks for the additional information. So, no chance without knowing whats inside of the dll?

Comment: Well, you could debug the assembly code, but if the DLL is anything beyond trivial, it will be quite hard, and probably easier to give a sample of your code that shows the problem to the people who develop the DLL, and say "Help, it's not working right??"

Comment: Does RunAnalytics take a reference to S_DATA or a pointer to S_DATA?  If it takes a reference, why are you saving a pointer to _im?